# how to get the node html passing a specific tag name

Tags: javascript

I have many nodes, i want to get this node when **data-th** is "Entrega"

```
<span class=“price” data-bind=“text: getValue(), attr: {‘data-th’: title}” data-th=“Entrega”>0.00</span>
```

is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: of course is possible. Please checkout for jquery framework or at least put a code snippet in javascript of what you've tried so far

Comment: Watch your quotes. You appear to be writing code with a word processor. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelector) to match that data attribute value.

Note: your HTML had smart quotes in it (perhaps from copying) but they will cause issues with your code functioning.

```js
const th = document.querySelector('span[data-th="Entrega"]');

console.log(th);
```

```html
<span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}" data-th="Entrega">0.00</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to loop throw all those spans and get the one you need.

```
object.getAttribute('data-th').includes('Entrega')
```

The code above gets the data attribute data-th from the object and check if it contains the string 'Entrega'.

For more information about data-attributes check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
function callFunction(){
  // GET ALL THE SPANS
  var spandata = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  
  // LOOP ON THAT
  Array.from(spandata).forEach(function(object){
  
  // THESE PRINT THE VALUE OF data-th
  console.log(object.getAttribute('data-th'));
  
    // IF ITS Entrega THEN DO SOMETHING
    if(object.getAttribute('data-th').includes('Entrega')){
      // DO SOMETHING HERE
      alert(object.getAttribute('data-th'));
    }
  })
}
```

```css
span{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class=“price” data-bind=“text: getValue(), attr: {‘data-th’: title}” data-th=“Entrega”>0.00</span>
  <span class=“price” data-bind=“text: getValue(), attr: {‘data-th’: title}” data-th=“Papa”>1.00</span>
  <span class=“price” data-bind=“text: getValue(), attr: {‘data-th’: title}” data-th=“Roach”>2.00</span>
  
<button onclick="callFunction()">print here</button>
```